# Use SharePoint Search to Refine a Document Library

Tags: search

I am looking for a way to to use SharePoint Search to search a document library and return items in relevance / rank order.

I have used the "Find a File" (see screenshot), but it returns all matches in alphabetical order, which isn't helpful when searching a large document library.

**Is there a Search web part or configuration which can search, rank and refine the contents of a Document Library Web Part on the page?**

[image: Find A File]

Comment: Why dont you just create a page with a searchbox webpart and a search result webpart? And configure the search results to pull data only from that library.?

Answer (score 0):

Once you execute the query you can change the sort based on the metadata in the libraries, but no, you cant order by rank. You can get to a refinable page by clicking the `Still didn't find it? Try searching the entire site.` link. Alternatively you could create a new search page that includes the features you want and scope the query to the library.

You could also try Metadata Navigation, it's not really "search" but it does add refinement to a list or library.